# Testing CSS styles and design elements of website

Tags: web-application, chrome, css, firebug

How to find the CSS attributes for website.
For eg: I have a testcase where I need to test the styling and design of a Button for webpage. How can I retrieve the elements, if for example I need find out the Size, Opacity, Colour for an element using Inspect element or firebug ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to inspect this *visually* (via matching screenshots) with a tool like [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com) or [Kantu](https://kantu.io)?

Comment: @Bobby231 Visually sometimes there are differences that gets away. I don't have much programming experience to user Sikuli or Kantu. How tough is it for a beginner to use such tools ?

Comment: Both, Kantu and Sikuli have a recorder, that makes it easy to get started (no programming required). On Windows I would recommend Kantu, and Sikuli for Mac and Linux.

Comment: Note that [Firebug is officially discontinued](https://getfirebug.com) and its users are advised to use the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Cribbing from an answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754469/export-css-of-dom-elements:

> Not a direct answer, but with Chrome Developer Tools, you can click
>   inside Styles or Computed Styles, hit Ctrl+A and then Ctrl+C to copy
>   all the styles in those given areas. It's not perfect in the Style tab
>   because it picks up some extra stuff. Better than selecting them one
>   by one I guess.

There's also [a javascript code answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7756455/759517) there that's pretty slick.

Comment: This is what I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: So it sounds like you already knew the answer to your question?  I'm confused.

Comment: I have already tried the direct answer you have mentioned, I was looking if there were other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automate this, I'm aware of two possibilities:

1. As [suggested by Bobby231](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26169/testing-css-styles-and-design-elements-of-website#comment29590_26169), you could use a visual testing tool such as [Depicted](https://github.com/bslatkin/dpxdt/) (open source) or [Applitools](https://applitools.com/) (closed source) to check the rendered result of the website against a [golden master](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/tags/characterization-testing/info).
2. There’s [recheck-web](https://github.com/retest/recheck-web) (open source; disclaimer: I work for retest, the company behind the project). recheck replaces asserts and checks everything at once, *including the CSS attributes of each element*. Here, you also have a golden master to compare against.